# Improved vs bettered

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context

Does saying that someone improved imply that there is a prior deficiency that needs to be remedied?

“She improved her best time again today and still has nationally the fastest time in the women’s division.”  To me, the word improved has a negative connotation that is unnecessary as she started with the fastest time of all competitors.  I would think that something like “bettered her best time” would be more positive.

Comment: What does a dictionary tell you?

Comment: They are near synonyms, but their idiomatic uses are different.  It's overly simplistic to assign the difference to a deficient vs non-deficient condition, however.

Comment: If you **improve** on a previous personal best running time, the new time is better and the older time is worse. Likewise, if you **better** a previous personal best running time, the new time is better and the older time is worse. Both expressions exist in a relative universe, and I don't see much to choose between them except that "better the mark" is (I believe) idiomatically more common. In neither case does the wording imply that the older personal best mark was deficient, except in the sense that anything short of perfection (including the new mark) is deficient.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the OP about the more positive connotation of **bettered**.

Shakespeare uses the word bettered in 'The Taming of the Shrew', II/1/957,

> Left solely heir to all his lands and goods, 
>   Which I have bettered rather than decreas'd.

[Shakespeare Concordance](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-results.php?link=con&searchtype=exact&works[]=tamingshrew&keyword1=bettered&sortby=WorkName&pleasewait=1&msg=sr)

Left a significant inheritance, the heir does not say that it is 'improved'
by their activities, but rather that it is bettered. The whole of it has been made more good - better. It didn't need improvement - there was nought wrong with it; but it can be yet better.

An 'improvement' would be mere addition of wealth, perhaps, or an extension of land. But to say that the whole of it is 'bettered' conveys - to me - a whole dimension of betterness that the word 'improve' would not supply.

---

The [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=improved%2Cbettered&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimproved%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbettered%3B%2Cc0) (improved, bettered) shows very little usage of the word against its more used neighbour. But I shall be making my own small contribution in the future to redress that balance.

The expression -

> nothing bettered, rather made worse

is also - to me - more powerful, in Mark 5:26, of the crippled woman. Despite spending so much money on doctors, she was worse rather than better.

She didn't need to be improved - she wanted to get better.

---

And it would be near to unthinkable to change this entry in the OED from 'bettered' to 'improved' :

[OED-3](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/18373?redirectedFrom=bettered#eid)

> 2012  A quest for knowledge that can lead to a **bettered** mankind has to be an eternal human condition.